# Need to test a MailService with Junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, jakarta-mail

How would i go about testing this with Junit? I am just confused on how to set this up using an xml file.

```
public void sendMailHire(User user, Job job){

    String email = user.getEmail();

    ApplicationContext mailContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            SPRING_MAIL_XML);

        try {
            Courier courier = (Courier) mailContext.getBean(COURIER);
            courier.sendMail(
                email,
                "Congratulations!",
                "Dear "
                    + user.getFirstName()
                    + " "
                    + user.getLastName()
                    + ", \n\nIt is our honor to inform you that you have been chosen for the position "
                    + job.getJobName()
                    + ".  Please contact our office for Orientation information.\nHuman Resources\nTechWannaBees\n(123) 456-7890");
        } finally {
            ((AbstractApplicationContext) mailContext).close();
        }

}
```

**JUnit testing to test that the mailContext is closed**

Comment: Which expectation do you want your test to cover? Do you want to test, that for example `user.getFirstName()` is called? Or do you want to test, that the mailContext is closed? Define some specific expectations, we can then help you to transform then into JUnit-TestCases.

Comment: That the mailContext is closed. sorry about that

Comment: When you answer a comment with additional information, you should usually update the original post with the information. That said, I don't understand what you mean by "setting this up using an xml file." JUnit has nothing to do with XML.

Answer (score 2):

If your expected result of a test is a method call (like a call of method `close()`), then you need a technique called **mocking**.

You have two options:

- Write **your own** mocking toolset
- Use an **existing mocking library** (like *Mockito*, *EasyMock*, *PowerMock*, etc.)

In short: *Mock* objects are "fake" objects, that implement real interfaces but simulate a specific behaviour.

In order to hand a mock object over to your code, you have to avoid calls to `new` in your code. I therefore replaced
`new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(SPRING_MAIL_XML)` with `applicationContextFactory.create(SPRING_MAIL_XML)`.

Your test (using Mockito 1.9.5) could look like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class MailerTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        // create mock objects
        ApplicationContextFactory factoryMock = mock(ApplicationContextFactory.class);
        ApplicationContext contextMock = mock(ApplicationContext.class);
        Courier courierMock = mock(Courier.class);

        // define behaviour of mocked objects
        when(factoryMock.create(anyString())).thenReturn(contextMock);
        when(contextMock.getBean(anyString())).thenReturn(courierMock);

        // run the production code
        new Mailer().sendMailHire(new User(), new Job(), factoryMock);

        // verify, that close has been called
        verify(contextMock).close();
    }

}
```

If you change your code to something like this:

```
interface ApplicationContextFactory {
    ApplicationContext create(String springMailXml);
}

class ApplicationContextFactoryImpl implements ApplicationContextFactory {
    public ApplicationContext create(String springMailXml) {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springMailXml);
    }
}

public class Mailer {

    ...

    public void sendMailHire(User user, Job job, ApplicationContextFactory applicationContextFactory){

        String email = user.getEmail();

        // don't call "new" here - use a factory, that can be mocked
        ApplicationContext mailContext = applicationContextFactory.create(SPRING_MAIL_XML);

        try {
            Courier courier = (Courier) mailContext.getBean(COURIER);
            courier.sendMail(
                    email,
                    "Congratulations!",
                    "Dear "
                            + user.getFirstName()
                            + " "
                            + user.getLastName()
                            + ", \n\nIt is our honor to inform you that you have been chosen for the position "
                            + job.getJobName()
                            + ".  Please contact our office for Orientation information.\nHuman Resources\nTechWannaBees\n(123) 456-7890");
        } finally {
            ((AbstractApplicationContext) mailContext).close();
        }

    }
}
```